# How can I add right-click option (context menu) on Brave, Chrome, Opera, Firefox browsers to play YouTube videos in MPV?

Tags: command-line, 22.04, browser, youtube, mpv-media-player

I use Chrome based-browsers (Brave, Opera) and Firefox. My OS is Ubuntu 22.04. I use this terminal command to play YouTube videos in MPV player:

```
mpv --ytdl-format="bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best" youtube-url
```

I copy the YouTube's video URL and add it to the command's text in a text editor, then I copy the entire command and paste it in terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The command works fine, but I want to automate the process through adding an option in the context menu when right-clicking on the YouTube's video Thumbnail or link.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this extension for Chrome-based browsers that seems to do what you want (haven't tried it myself though): [Play with MPV](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-with-mpv/hahklcmnfgffdlchjigehabfbiigleji)

According to the [extension's GitHub page](https://github.com/ksyasuda/play-with-mpv-ytdlp), you can install it by following the steps below:

> 1. Install [MPV](https://mpv.io/installation/)
> 2. Install [python 2 or 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)
> 3. Install [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-with-mpv/hahklcmnfgffdlchjigehabfbiigleji)
> 4. Run `pip install git+git://github.com/thann/play-with-mpv --user`
> 5. Start server by running `play-with-mpv` (or use the Linux *free desktop* shortcut)

You can then right-click a video link in your browser and select *Play with MPV*.

---

An alternative is to use a `zenity` dialog in which you can paste the URL of the video and play it in MPV. You can do that as follows:

1. Create a script in the location of your choice and add the following:

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash

   yt_link=$(zenity --entry --title "Play in MPV" --text "Enter link to watch in MPV:")

   mpv --ytdl-format="bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best" "$yt_link"
   ```
2. Give execution rights to the script:

   ```
   chmod u+x /path/to/your/script.sh
   ```

   Make sure to replace `/path/to/your/script.sh` with the actual path to your script.
3. [Create a keyboard shortcut](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html) that will run your script.

That's it! Now, if you use the shortcut you created, you will be presented with a window like the one below:

[image: Zenity dialog]

Enter the URL of the video in the dialog and click *OK* or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to play the video in MPV.